# Stored Procedure to create stored procedure from dynamic sql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want dynamic sql to create a stored procedure in mysql. For Example:

```
delimiter ///

create procedure x1()
begin

set @sql = '
drop procedure if exists x2;

delimiter ///

create procedure x2()
begin

    INSERT INTO `world`.`city`
    (`Name`,
    `CountryCode`,
    `District`,
    `Population`)
    VALUES
    (''Meyerton'',
    ''ZAR'',
    ''Africa'',
    500);


end ///

delimiter ;

call x2();

drop procedure if exists x2;';

prepare stmt1 from @sql;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;

end ///

delimiter ;

call x1();
```

but when ever I call procedure `x1` I get the following error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER ///  CREATE PROCEDURE 20140416_TriggerSP_NoUserFound() BEGIN  DECLARE ' at line 3`

This is the actual trigger from the sql code. the sql code above is a very simplified version of what the actual sql code is.

So the question is, can dynamic sql in a stored procedure create a stored procedure in mysql ?
If needed Ill load the original SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MySQL 5.5 [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

> The following SQL statements can be used as prepared statements:

```
ALTER TABLE
ANALYZE TABLE
CACHE INDEX
CALL
CHANGE MASTER
CHECKSUM {TABLE | TABLES}
COMMIT
{CREATE | RENAME | DROP} DATABASE
{CREATE | DROP} INDEX
{CREATE | RENAME | DROP} TABLE
{CREATE | RENAME | DROP} USER
{CREATE | DROP} VIEW
DELETE
DO
FLUSH {TABLE | TABLES | TABLES WITH READ LOCK | HOSTS | PRIVILEGES
  | LOGS | STATUS | MASTER | SLAVE | DES_KEY_FILE | USER_RESOURCES}
GRANT
INSERT
INSTALL PLUGIN
KILL
LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE
OPTIMIZE TABLE
REPAIR TABLE
REPLACE
RESET {MASTER | SLAVE | QUERY CACHE}
REVOKE
SELECT
SET
SHOW {AUTHORS | CONTRIBUTORS | WARNINGS | ERRORS}
SHOW BINLOG EVENTS
SHOW CREATE {PROCEDURE | FUNCTION | EVENT | TABLE | VIEW}
SHOW {MASTER | BINARY} LOGS
SHOW {MASTER | SLAVE} STATUS
SLAVE {START | STOP}
TRUNCATE TABLE
UNINSTALL PLUGIN
UPDATE
```

> Other statements are not supported in MySQL 5.5.

Therefore creating procedures is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

You can not create a stored procedure using dynamic SQL in mysql.

If you take that sql text and run it in mysql workbench you will see that no matter what stored procedures you create using dynamic sql it will fail.

Comment: Just to let you know, the goal of stackoverflow (although it doesn't seem so at first sight) is, to be some kind of wiki. Therefore answers including facts are appreciated, including the source.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that my answer was a bit vague and not very informative